# Add Dynamic Elements In Forms

Tags: form

I'm needing to add a dynamically added dropdown input field for my form, as is commonly done with javascript.  How would this be possible?

In other words, there may be more than 1 dropdown desired by the user, and I need a link or button that would create any additional desired dropdown inputs.

Thanks

Comment: As the forms are typically created by using the Control Panel interface, and not programatically, how would a workable modification to a form be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Field Type or you can use [dynamicfields](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields) in order to gain dynamic inputs. Or is it just about hiding/showing specific values in Javascript and not really about Craft at all?